# Creating CAPTCHA in ColdFusion then showing image in Vue.js

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, vue.js, captcha

I am trying to create a CAPTCHA image on ColdFusion. ColdFusion will be producing REST services and hence will have to push the image via JSON. I want the image to be self contained. I don't want to expose any of the servers paths, so I am going to encode the image and push that via JSON. Last but not least, Vue.js will be used to show the image on the page.

Note: I have omitted the AJAX part for clarity.

```
<cfscript>
  // This is ColdFusion
  tempFile = "ram:///myImage.txt";

  myImage = ImageCreateCaptcha(100, 300, "Blackcat", "high");

  ImageWriteBase64(myImage, tempFile, "png",true, true);

  myfile = FileRead(tempFile);
  FileDelete(tempFile);
</cfscript>



<div id="image">
   <img :src="captcha">
</div>


<script>
  // this is JavaScript

  data = { 'captcha' : <cfoutput>'#myfile#'</cfoutput> };

  new Vue({
      el: '#image',
      data : data
      });
</script>
```

Can this process be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with storing intermediate data to disk, including RAM disk. Because it is shared by the whole server, it is even worse than a global variable! The data you write may not be the data you read.